# How sql compares date stored in varchar datatype

Tags: sql, oracle, date, comparison, varchar

How a comparison between two dates are made if both are stored in varchar?

I came across a table which is written years ago in which the date (DD-MM-YY) is stored in a varchar
format

```
updated_date varchar(255)
```

There's a script written for delete operation in following manner

(Temp variable)-

```
temp_date_tocompare varchar2(255) :=to_char(sysdate-7, 'YYYY-MM-DD')

delete from myTable
    where updated_date < temp_date_tocompare;
```

I executed this and it works fine.

But curious to understand behind the scenes work, how this varchars are compared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare dates *as dates*.  Store date/times using proper date/time formats.  Do not store them as strings!

Your code will no doubt delete rows.  Whether it deletes the rows you want is another question.  The logic you want seems to be:

```
delete from myTable
    where to_date(updated_date, 'DD-MM-YY') < trunc(sysdate) - 7;
```

Comment: isn't it will be a overhead to each time convert every row value to date and then do comparison as that delete operation deletes millions of rows

Comment: @Shweta . . . Of course it is (although much less than the overhead for the actual `delete`).  If you stored the values using the correct data types, that would not be an issue.

Comment: Actually this is very old table and we cant make changes in to it.

Comment: You can put a function-based index on the column to make the comparison less painful.